# How can I get wikipedia xml page including all information which I need?

Tags: wikipedia, wiki, wikipedia-api, wikidata-api, pywikibot

I have enwiki-20110115-abstract.xml as the follwing in the image 1: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/948V7.png)

I have also enwiki-20110115-pages-articles.xml as the following image 2 : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad5FX.png)

What I need is the all information tags  in the first file (enwiki-20110115-abstract.xml) and the redirect information from the second file(enwiki-20110115-pages-articles.xml) for the same Wikipedia page.Please is there any version of Wikipedia which has both this information or can I do something to get this data? I thought about joining bothfiles but it will be very expensive computation.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pywikibot has a XMLDumpPageGenerator implemented in pagegenerators and a xmlreader module